# How to get TeamCity to exclude nunit test categories?

Tags: configuration, nunit, continuous-integration, teamcity

I am using the TeamCity VisualStudio sln configuration to drive my CI build.  It runs all my NUnit tests - which is all well and great but I don't want TeamCity running any of my tests with the [Category("DatabaseTests")] attribute (since they hit an actual database).

In the NUnit configuration under categories to exclude  I put simply **DatabaseTests** but its not working.  Is there something I'm missing?  Is there a way that I can see what teamcity is sending to the nunit runner?

Comment: I'm having this problem too with TeamCity 8, what did you do to resolve this issue?

Comment: @James I've since started putting all my trully unit tests in one assembly and a separate project for `IntegrationTests`. That way there's no accidents with someone meaning to run just unit tests and then it taking too long or arbitrarily failing

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm pretty sure this has worked for me in the past on another project, but now I cannot get TeamCity to ignore the category for anything. I've checked and double checked the test and the TC config. Doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn on DEBUG mode:

> to enable 'DEBUG' log level for TeamCity classes. To do it, edit the logs/teamcity-
>   (server|agent)-log4j.xml file by
>   removing all the lines containing
>    comment. After that,
>   DEBUG messages will go to
>   teamcity-*.log files.
>
> Make sure the logs are rotated by
>   default. When debug is enabled it
>   makes sense to increase maxBackupIndex
>   value in the relevant appender tag to
>   10 or even 20 files (ensure there is
>   sufficient free disk space available).

...which I got from their [docs](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TCD4/Reporting+Issues).  And then you can see what is happening.